# Android 12 crash latest react-native-track-player version

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

After updating app in android 12 and try to run app in android 12 device and simulator facing issue for crashing.

**Here is issue.**
androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'

**Resolve**
With use of **android:exported="true"** fixed issue for run app but service not start once player on in app. so again crash app.

Comment: You can refer to this answer too. might help to solve the case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72441909/12215054

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Github for React-Native-Track-Player.

There is a Beta version for use with Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

Following this question, anyone was able to patch the package to make it work on Android 12?  Using a non-final version seems more buggy than just adapting the stable one.